# How to assign an alias to a module on import?

Tags: go, echo

The manual gives an example:

```
t := &Template{
    templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("public/views/*.html")),
}
```

in which templates are compiled along the path `public/views/*.html`.

I need to change this code so that templates are compiled not in one, but in two specified paths, namely `pjt_*/templates/include/*.html` and `pjt_*/templates/site/*.html`.

My code:

```
package main

import(
"html/template"
"io"
"net/http"

"github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type TemplateRenderer struct {
templates *template.Template
}

func (t *TemplateRenderer) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {

if viewContext, isMap := data.(map[string]interface{}); isMap {
viewContext["reverse"] = c.Echo().Reverse
}

return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}

func main() {
  e := echo.New()
  e.Renderer = &TemplateRenderer{
      // here I want templates to be compiled, not only for
      // "pjt_*/templates/include/*.html" but also "pjt_*/templates/site/*.html"
      templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("pjt_*/templates/include/*.html")),
  }

  e.GET("/something", func(c echo.Context) error {
      return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "template.html", "World")
  })

  e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8000"))
}
```

PS guide, just in case: https://echo.labstack.com/guide/templates/

Answer (score 0):

[template.ParseGlob](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template@go1.19#ParseGlob) takes a pattern and parses the template definitions from the files identified by the pattern.

Call it with a pattern that matches both of `pjt_*/templates/include/*.html` and `pjt_*/templates/site/*.html`.

Comment: Didn't figure out how to call `ParseGlob` with a template that matches both `pjt_*/templates/include/*.html` and `pjt_*/templates/site/*.html`

Comment: Call parseGlob with a string pattern that matches both the directories. like

`template.ParseGlob("pjt_*/templates/*/*.html")` should compile templates at both `pjt_*/templates/include/*.html` and `pjt_*/templates/site/*.html`

Comment: Templates will contain folders with templates that do not need to be compiled. Therefore, excuse me, I will insist on solving the question asked